# How does でも嫌でも続ける事は work here?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing with a japanese penfriend on italki, and I've got a few problems with what she has written me in japanese ^^

For context: Amongst other things, I've written her that I've changed my profession. I successfully finished my studies to become a teacher, but I've changed into the IT-sector because in my country (germany, bavaria) there is no need for teachers on schools anymore for the subjects I've studied.

Now, I haven't written her this backgroundinformation and as far as I can understand, she tries to convince to go for it :D The problem is, as I said, that  I don't understand everything she has written me.

So first, the full text:
仕事を始めるとき、最初の何年かはとても大変ですね。でも嫌でも続ける事は、何か自分に意味があります。そういうふうに、日本では言います。だから、本当に自分のしたい事が今できなくても、できるときがくるので、そのときまで粘ってください！かな？？？

Now, about the sentence in question:
でも嫌でも続ける事は、何か自分に意味があります。
=>"However unpleasant continuation is/it is to continue, there is some meaning to oneself."
Although this makeshift translation seems to work, I feel unsure about interpretation of 続ける事, and therefore also about my further interpretation of the second half. 
That's why I want to ask for confimation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is basically correct. It's yet another example of "double subject" sentence which both uses は and が. AはBがある literally means "As for A, there is B", but you can simply translated it as "A has B."

Here, A is "嫌でも続ける事" and B is "(何か)意味". 嫌でも modifies 続ける. 自分に modifies あります and means "to you" or "for you".

> でも{嫌でも続ける事}は、何か自分に意味があります。
>   However, {keep on doing it even though it's unpleasant} has some meaning to you.

Maybe she was thinking of [this Japanese proverb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42296/5010).